# Blocking a buffer in a multiple buffer system while continuing the rest of the process

Tags: simpy

I am currently working with Simpy, and I want to model a parallel queueing system. There are 4 buffers, each storing products. A product can be taken out, but the buffer must then wait 15 minutes for the next product to be taken out. Each buffer has a capacity of 1, but products can be stored while these 15 minutes go by. I have tried solving this using env.timeout(15), but this times the entire system out for 15 minutes. How do I block only the buffer, not the full system?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your timeout with a yield?

I did this by using a queue of queues (queueQueue) and then breaking the get process into three steps,  pull the queue from queueQueue, then pull the obj from the queue.  the queue will not get any more requests until it is returned to queueQueue.  I wait until the obj get request is filled (can be a delay if the queue is empty and needs to wait for a obj to be added), then I make a async call (no yeild) to a process to wait 15 minuets and then put the queue back into queueQueue.  Calling this process without a yield keeps the main process from getting blocked.

take a look and see if this works for you

```
"""
example where given a pool of queues, once a queue has a get request, block the queue from getting 
furture get requests until 15 minutes after the request is filled.  Note the queue could be empty 
and therefore not fill the request immeditly.  The queue can still get put requests

The two features is a queueQueue which has queue that are ready to process requests.
if a queue is not in the queueQueue it does not get any requests

Second, the process of putting a queue back in the queueQueue is wrapped in a process that can 
be called async (no yield) so it does not block the main process

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class Obj():
    """
    dummy object to queue

    has unique IDs
    """
    
    # id counter
    id = 0

    def __init__(self):

        # assign unique id
        Obj.id += 1
        self.id = Obj.id

def getObj(env, queueQueue):
    """
    gets a queue, then gets a obj

    if the queue does not have a obj then will wait until a obj is added to the queue
    once the obj request if filled by the queue the queue is sent to the putQueue process 
    async (no yield) which waits 15 mins before putting the queue in the queueQueue
    """

    # wait for a queue to become available
    queue = yield queueQueue.get()
    print(f'{env.now} queue {queue.id} has been pulled')

    # wait for obj from queue

    obj = yield queue.get()
    print(f'{env.now} obj {obj.id} has been pulled from queue {queue.id}')

    # do not block while watting 15 min (do not use yield here)
    env.process(putQueue( env, queueQueue, queue))

    return obj

def putQueue(env, queueQueue, queue):
    """
    waits 15 minutes and puts a queuue in a queue of queues
    """

    yield env.timeout(15)
    yield queueQueue.put(queue)
    print(f'{env.now} queue {queue.id} has been queued')

def genObj(env, queueList):
    """
    load the queues with objects.
    uses round robin to select queue to add to
    """

    while True:
        # create a obj for the queue and give it a tracking id  
        obj = Obj()
        

        # get the next queue and add obj (queues are filled round robin)
        q = obj.id % 4
        yield queueList[q].put(obj)
        print(f'{env.now} added obj {obj.id} to queue {queueList[q].id}')

        # queue fill rate
        yield env.timeout(random.triangular(10,20,15))
        

def consume(env, id, queueQueue):
    """
    consumer that make queue get requests from the pool of queues
    """

    while True:
        # comsuption rate
        yield env.timeout(random.triangular(10,20,14))
        
        # wraps getting a queue, get a obj from the queue, and queueing the queue
        obj = yield env.process(getObj(env,queueQueue))

        print(f'{env.now} consumer: {id} pulled obj {obj.id}')

env = simpy.Environment()

# the queue of queues
queueQueue = simpy.Store(env, capacity=4)

# the pool of queues with queued obj
queueList = []
for i in range(4):
    queue = simpy.Store(env)
    queue.id = i+1
    queueList.append(queue)
    queueQueue.put(queue)
    print('queue',queue.id)

# start queuing obj (update code to change queue rate)
env.process(genObj(env,queueList))

# start consumming obj (can add more of these)
env.process(consume(env, 1, queueQueue))

env.run(200)
print('done')
```